# Get a SQL query hash without (ignoring) parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, mariadb

I have tons of queries and wanna count their occurrence.

**Problem**: the same query can have different parameters.

I thought about using `EXPLAIN` and then hash the array.
But i guess that wont work well.

Is there any way to get a hash of a query without including the params and "style" *(format?)*?
*F.e. can the mysql (mariadb) server return a prepared statement from a query?*
*(EDIT: i do not have the prepared statements from code. I got SQL strings only.)*

Simple example:
`SELECT * FROM foo where bar = 'baz`
`` SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = 'baz'; ``
`` SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = 3 ``
`` SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = 3; ``
...
This is the same query with different "style" and different parameters.
What i would like to count up is the occurrence of `` SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = {.*}; ``

*Note: the queries will contain multiple joins, subqueries, ect.*

---

In this case I got those SQL queries from a `general_log` table.
No code, just SQL strings.
It's *not* a question of "how can I do this better".
It's a "how can I get a better result from what I got".

Comment: "...Problem: the same query can have different parameters..." - If you are using parameterized SQL statements, this is not a problem. And, you should be using parameterized SQL statements for a variety of reasons including security, caching, performance, debugging, alerts, etc.

Comment: I ofc agree. But in this case I got those SQL queries from a `general_log` table.
No code, just SQL strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of queries by "digest" — a kind of anonymized version of the query with all constant values replaced with `?` — from the performance_schema.

```
SELECT
SCHEMA_NAME,
digest,
digest_text,
round(sum_timer_wait/ 1000000000000, 6),
count_star
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest
ORDER BY sum_timer_wait DESC LIMIT 10;
```

See https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/10/13/mysql-query-digest-with-performance-schema/ for a blog on this solution.

Comment: Note I have tested this query on MySQL 8.0, but I can't guarantee it works the same on MariaDB. I don't use MariaDB, and it's not necessarily compatible with MySQL in all cases.